# How to show $\mathcal L_{\nabla f} g= \nabla ^2 f$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

$M^n \subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$ is smooth hypersurface. $\nabla $ is Euclidean connection. $g$ is induced metric. $f$ is a function on $M$. How to show 
$$
\mathcal L_{\nabla f} g= \nabla ^2 f
$$

This question is from the conformal tangent vector ($\mathcal L_X g=\lambda g$). I see a another definition that $\nabla f$ is conformal if $\nabla ^2 f =\lambda g$. So , I try to prove $\mathcal L_{\nabla f} g= \nabla ^2 f$.

But as [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative#The_Lie_derivative_of_a_tensor_field), 
$$
\mathcal L_Xg= (X^c \partial_c g_{ab}+g_{cb}\partial_a X^c + g_{ca} \partial _b X^c) dx^a\otimes dx^b
$$
I  can't turn it to $\nabla ^2 f$.

Besides, in Euclidean space, how to show $\nabla^2 |x|=\frac{1}{|x|}(g+\nabla|x| \otimes \nabla |x|)$  ?

Comment: In your equation for the Hessian of the norm in Euclidean space, you should probably have $d|x|$ instead of $\nabla|x|$. The way you have it stated the right hand side is a $(2,2)$-type tensor field, whereas the left hand side is a $(0,2)$-type tensor field. Also, what definition of the Hessian are you using? I've usually seen the surface Hessian defined as the Lie derivative of the metric with respect to the gradient. (Actually, it is usually $1/2\mathcal{L}_{\nabla f}g$... the factor of $1/2$ is there to make this definition of the Hessian coincide with the usual Hessian in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: @YousufSoliman: how is it $(2,2)$? If you're insisting that $\nabla$ always means the contravariant gradient when acting on functions then it's some wacky mix of $(0,2)$ and $(2,0)$ if anything; but using $\nabla f$ and $df$ interchangeably is pretty standard.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Ahh my bad. I've only recently started learning Riemannian geometry, and I've never seen it written that way. Thanks for pointing that out and my bad for previous comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\L{\mathcal L}$
From the product rule for the Lie derivative we have $$\L_X g (Y,Z) = X(g(Y,Z)) - g(\L_X Y,Z) - g(Y, \L_X Z).$$

Expanding the first term using the metric-compability of $\nabla$ and the second two terms using the fact that $\nabla$ is torsion-free we get

$$ \L_X g(Y,Z) = g(\nabla_X Y,Z) + g(Y, \nabla_X Z) - g(\nabla_X Y - \nabla_Y X,Z) - g(Y, \nabla_X Z - \nabla_Z X) \\ =g(\nabla_Y X,Z)+g(Y,\nabla_Z X).$$

Thus $\L_X g$ is twice the symmetrization of the tensor obtained by lowering the index of $\nabla X$; so $$\L_{\mathrm{grad}f} g=2\mathrm{Sym}(\nabla\nabla f)=2\nabla^2 f$$ since the Hessian is already symmetric.

Your second question should be a simple coordinate calculation - just show $$\partial_i \partial_j |x| = \frac 1 {|x|} (\delta_{ij} + \partial_i |x| \partial_j |x|).$$ The product rule applied to $|x|^2$ should help.

Comment: ${\rm grad}$ is (y)